# I'm trying to make a grid of clickable boxes where boxes know which other boxes they're adjacent to. JS/React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

I'll post my code in a second, but I really need an approach more than a bugfix.  My code works I'm just not sure the best approach for the next step.

The basic usage of my app is that users input two numbers (height/width) to specify the size of a grid.  Then the app sends data to the stylesheet to fill in CSS variables which makes a CSS Grid in those dimensions.  The app generates the grid with one box (a `<div>`) in each grid square.  Each `<div>` will be clickable so that the user can attach certain data to it from a hardcoded library I'll manually build.  Also, I want to do things that require the app to recognize all contiguous squares with identical data and perform an operation on them collectively, which means each square has to know which squares are above/below/left/right of them.

I've found examples, but only in cases where a grid is not variable in size.  My grid is generated per user-inputted dimensions.

In real-world terms, I'm building a crop layout planner for Stardew Valley.  Most apps I've found are just calendar apps; see what days you plant crops and what day they'll be ready.  I actually want a clickable grid the user can insert corn, wheat, sunflower, etc.  And other tools like scarecrows, sprinklers, etc.  This means overlays which means the grid "knowing" where each square is in relation others.

The most straightforward way IMO should be to use CSS variables with `grid-template-area`, but this seems like it'll end up with a lot of complicated regex and I can't find examples of anyone ever doing it successfully.  I can't hardcode grid area names because the grid can be a different size every render.  I also can't find documentation of `gird-template-area` accepting logic that would simply figure it out.

The next option I think is to build in mathematical logic to for the app to calculate which squares are above and below it, which shouldn't be TOO hard because I'm making basic rectangular grids.  No funny shapes.  It'll be some bloated logic but it feels doable.

I'm doing this in React but there's no reason the solution can't be vanilla JS embedded in my React project.  In fact it presumably would be.  I just feel like there must be an easier solution or a JS/React library that does this which I haven't come across.  Or maybe I've discovered the library I'm going to make.

This is the main function which is taking user input to generate the grid.  I think it's straightforward enough:

```
function Landing() {
    const [numberAcross, setNumberAcross] = useState(0);
    const [numberDown, setNumberDown] = useState(0);    

    const getGridSize = () => {
        const inputAcross = document.getElementById('boxes-across').value;
        const numberAcross = parseInt(inputAcross);
        setNumberAcross(numberAcross);
        const inputDown = document.getElementById('boxes-down').value;
        const numberDown = parseInt(inputDown);
        setNumberDown(numberDown);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <label htmlFor='boxes-across'>Across (1-20):</label>
            <input type='number' id='boxes-across' name='boxes-across' min='1' max='20' />

            <br />

            <label htmlFor='boxes-down'>Down (1-20):</label>
            <input type='number' id='boxes-down' name='boxes-down' min='1' max='20' />

            <br />

            <button onClick={getGridSize}>Make Grid!</button>

            <hr />

            <div className='flexbox-center-me'>
                <p>Across: {numberAcross} {typeof numberAcross}</p>
                <p>Down: {numberDown} {typeof numberDown}</p>

                <CropGrid numberOfColumns={numberAcross} numberOfRows={numberDown}/>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Landing;
```

User input is held in state in that component then passed to this as a prop:

```
function CropGrid(props) {
    const { numberOfColumns, numberOfRows } = props;

    const squares = new Array(numberOfColumns * numberOfRows).fill(1);
    const cropSquares = squares.map((square, idx) => <CropSquare squareNumber={idx} />)

    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--rows', numberOfRows);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--columns', numberOfColumns);

    return (
        <div id='crop-grid'>
            {cropSquares}
        </div>
    );
}

export default CropGrid;
```

CSS to generate the grid layout:

```
#crop-grid {
    align-self: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 2rem);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 2rem);
    min-width: 1rem;
    min-height: 1rem;
    outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

And here's the individual `<div>` being called to render in each grid space:

```
function CropSquare(props) {
    const {squareNumber} = props;
    const idString = `crop-grid-square-${squareNumber}`;
    return (
        <div className='crop-grid-square' id={idString} key={idString} />
    );
}

export default CropSquare;
```

Comment: I think you can follow this guy's javascript approach to finding adjacent grid items of a given grid square by using a matrix: https://kozmicluis.com/adjacent-cells-of-a-matrix/.  His function may be of use to you once you enter the dimensions of your grid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach the task by using data attributes. I'd tell each cell what position it occupies in the grid, then query this when a cell is clicked, before using that cells row and column info to select its neighbours. You could easily store some other info here in a data attribute and use that as a means of selecting similar elements that may or may not be direct neighbours.

I guess something like this might work for you.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(event)
{
    let nRows = 6, nCols = 6;
    
    for (let y=0; y<nRows; y++)
    {
        for (let x=0; x<nCols; x++)
        {
            let cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.classList.add('cell');
            cell.dataset.row = y;
            cell.dataset.col = x;
            cell.addEventListener('click', onCellClick, false);
            document.body.appendChild(cell);
        }
        document.body.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
    }
}

function onCellClick(event)
{
    let cell = this;
    let row = parseInt(cell.dataset.row), col = parseInt(cell.dataset.col);
    
    let lastHighlighted = document.querySelectorAll('.highlight');
    lastHighlighted.forEach( elem => elem.classList.remove('highlight') );
    
    let firstDone = false;
    let cssSelStr = '';
    
    for (let y=row-1; y<row+2; y++)
    {
        for (let x=col-1; x<col+2; x++)
        {
            if (firstDone)
                cssSelStr += ", ";
            cssSelStr += `div[data-row="${y}"][data-col="${x}"]`;
            firstDone = true;
        }
    }

    let highlightCells = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelStr);
    highlightCells.forEach( cell => cell.classList.add('highlight') );
}
```

```css
.cell{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: solid 1px #888;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 4px;
}
.highlight
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: #AFA;
}
```

Comment: I like this.  I was probably going to use the numerical ids to and logic have the code "figure out" which squares per id are above/below/left/right and storing that in state.  But now that I think about it, simply specifying a row/column for state and having code to navigate the grid later sounds a lot more flexible.  Thanks!